# creating a new data frame by subsetting and manipulating an existing data frame in one step using dplyr

Tags: r, subset, dplyr

So I am trying to learn how to use dplyr and some basic procedures are eluding me.

For example, the following is pretty simple in base, but I don't know how to replicate it in dplyr in a single step.

```
 my_data <- with(mtcars, data.frame(   cylinders = cyl[cyl == 6], 
                                       twice_weight = wt[cyl == 6]*2))
```

I could create the variable twice_weight with mutate() and then subset the result with select(), but that seems cumbersome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could also do:

```
filter(mtcars, cyl == 6) %>%
  transmute(cylinders = cyl, twice_weight = wt*2)

#  cylinders twice_weight
#1         6         5.24
#2         6         5.75
#3         6         6.43
#4         6         6.92
#5         6         6.88
#6         6         6.88
#7         6         5.54
```

.. `transmute` drops all columns except for those that are explicitly called inside it and grouping variables.

Comment: the `transmute` is what I was looking for

Comment: welcome, @Michael. Btw, if you didn't mind the slightly different column name, you could also change the transmute to: `transmute(cyl, twice_weight = wt*2)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
      filter(cyl==6) %>% 
      mutate(twice_weight=wt*2) %>% 
      select(cylinders=cyl, twice_weight)
#   cylinders twice_weight
#1         6         5.24
#2         6         5.75
#3         6         6.43
#4         6         6.92
#5         6         6.88
#6         6         6.88
#7         6         5.54
```

Comment: well there you go! not too cumbersome I suppose. Now I just gotta get used to those "%>%" operators!